# How to remove specific element from the layer in kinetic js

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm using kinetic js to add some images and shapes to the layer in canvas. But I have a problem in removing a specific element from the layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to do the following with the added element

```
addedElement.remove();
layer.draw(); //this will draw the updated layer
```